# strange NAT issues with pfSense to vagrant VM

Tags: linux-networking, pfsense, vagrant, docker-networking

This one has got me confused:

I have a pfSense firewall (let's call it `pfs`) and behind it several servers.
I NAT several services from my public IP to different servers on the LAN without any issues.

On one of the servers (let's call it `s1`) I'm running a `vagrant` (with `libvirt`) VM (let's call it `v1`) with a **public** network configured, which gets IP `192.168.1.159` via `pfs`s DHCP server.

Now I configure a simple NAT on `pfs` to access `s1`'s SSH, say `<wan>:6622 -> s1:22` and access it on `mydomain.com:6622`. No problem.

I can also access `v1:22` (or the equivalent `192.168.1.159:22`) with a valid ssh user *from within the LAN* without issue.

Now I add a simple NAT on `pfs`, say `<wan>:6722 -> v1:22`. Now trying to access `mydomain.com:6722` **does not** work?!

The objective is to add even "another layer": running containers with public ports, e.g. `--publish 9980:80` on `v1` and access them as e.g. `v1:9980` and from `mydomain.com:9980` with the corresponding NAT on `pfs` like `<wan>:9980 -> v1:9980`. *From the LAN* this is also working as expected (i.e. I can access `v1:9980` from the LAN), but a NAT via `pfs` is not.

I have similar setups working within the same network on different machines without problems. I even have another (non-vagrant, but also `libvirt`) VM on `s1` to which I can ssh over NAT via my public IP perfectly fine. But somehow the above doesn't work with the `vagrant` machine, and I'm really at a loss what might be causing this issue. (FWIW I have `net.ipv4.forward` enabled on `v1`).

#### EDIT:

I got one step closer: if I nuke the first existing NIC of the `vagrant` VM using `virt-manager`, and set the second VM to `rtl8139` instead of `virtio` (and then restart), I lose `vagrant ssh` capability but NAT then works. So the question then becomes: how to configure via `vagrant` provisioning such that we have a similar config, I suppose that means that the public network must be on the default interface then?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

The cause is that `vagrant` requires (and therefore configures) its local interface (private network) as primary, with no standard method to override that. (Some info is [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network), but the `vagrant` people admit that they're themselves confused by the topic...)

A (more robust) variation on the concept to tweak the default routes brought the solution. I'm using an `ansible` provisioner, where I execute the following (on the guest, via the provisioning playbook):

```yaml
  - name: remove wrong default route on eth0 (again)
    shell: |
      eval $(route -n | awk '$0~/[.0]{4}/ && $3~/[.0]{4}/ && $8~/eth0/ { printf "ip route del default via %s dev %s; ",$3,$8 }')
```

(interestingly it needs to be executed twice (or after a while?), possibly because the network hasn't come up fully when the provision script started?)

This removes the default route on `eth0` (the `public_network` would only be automatically configured on `eth1` by `vagrant`) and makes external connections work as expected. This is presumably (speculating here) due to the fact that responses to incoming NATed requests are routed to the firewall via the default route on `eth0` by default (which by `vagrant` default has priority), which confuses the NAT FW because it came in on the VM's `eth1`. So removing `eth0` as default replies to external requests on the same interface as they came in on.